# How to subscribe to multiple channels in Golang

Tags: go

It use the golang's channel.
How to make st2 to display propertly in the following code:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "github.com/OpinionatedGeek/go-bittrex"
)

func main() {
 bt := bittrex.New("", "")
 ch := make(chan bittrex.ExchangeState, 16)
 go func() {
    for st := range ch1 {
        fmt.Println("Message:", st)
    }
    for st2 := range ch2 {
        fmt.Println("Message:", st2)
    }
}()

bt1.SubscribeExchangeUpdate("BTC-NEO", ch1, nil)
bt2.SubscribeExchangeUpdate("BTC-ETC", ch2, nil)
```

The problem here is that:
it only BTC-NEO working. it looks BTC-ETC is just ignored.
How to subscribe both of them?

the reference link is at:
https://github.com/OpinionatedGeek/go-bittrex/blob/master/ws.go

Comment: I think you should read in detail for about the question.

Comment: Then it's not clear what you're asking. Go has no concept of "subscribing" to a channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution is to set go for the first SubscribeExchangeUpdate
so

```
go bt1.SubscribeExchangeUpdate("BTC-NEO", ch1, nil)
bt2.SubscribeExchangeUpdate("BTC-ETC", ch2, nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wait for multiply channels in single gouroutine using `select` statement: https://play.golang.com/p/1PUfSyG0HHZ

More links:

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements

Comment: thanks your answer. but I think the major problem , I finally found the problem is in subscription will block the thread, so the second one does not go through.